# Laravel type error: Argument 1 passed must be array string given

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to get an email to reset the admin password and i get this error when he process the token.

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager::createTokenRepository() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/Manifiesto2017/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php on line 71
```

The lines are this:

```
protected function resolve($name)
{
    $config = $this->getConfig($name);

    if (is_null($config)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
    }

    // The password broker uses a token repository to validate tokens and send user
    // password e-mails, as well as validating that password reset process as an
    // aggregate service of sorts providing a convenient interface for resets.
    return new PasswordBroker(
        $this->createTokenRepository($config),   <!--THIS!!!!
        $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'])
    );
}
```

And the createtokenrepository function is this:

```
protected function createTokenRepository(array $config)
{
    $key = $this->app['config']['app.key'];

    if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
        $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
    }

    $connection = isset($config['connection']) ? $config['connection'] : null;

    return new DatabaseTokenRepository(
        $this->app['db']->connection($connection),
        $this->app['hash'],
        $config['table'],
        $key,
        $config['expire']
    );
}
```

I can't see where's the error, any help will be appreciated.

**SOLVED**

The problem was in line $config = $this->getConfig($name) only takes 'admins' and don't take the table, expire time..

File auth.php was wrong, looks like this at the bottom:

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],
```

And should look like this:

```
  'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Look again at error to figure out which line has error

Comment: The line with the error is: $this->createTokenRepository($config). And inf function createtokenrepository i give an array $config..

Comment: I guess  $this->getConfig($name) returns a string and not an array

Comment: Seems `$this->getConfig()` takes array as parameter you are giving an string `$name` there

Comment: Yes.. i think that's the problem. But how can i do to fix it and takes array and not string? I'm following a video and i see it around 3-4 times.. i think i don't forget nothing, also i download the source code and look it and nothing.. anyway, vendor have "base" of laravel config, i think should work how comes..

Comment: Yes guys, $name have the value "admins" but anyway don't know how to fix it and make it an array..

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks a lot for your fast answers, you made me check the config and with a debugger i see the problem. On config/auth.php i don't declare correctly the reset passwords for admins. I will write it on the question.Thanks a lot again.